# How do I set a default datetime parameter in a stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, sybase, default-parameters

I have declared a stored procedure in Sybase, and one of the parameters is of type datetime. Now I want to assign this datetime a default value.

Here's the declaration:

```
create procedure Procedure 
(
    @fromDate datetime = getdate()
)
...
```

However Sybase is giving me an error

```
Number (102) Severity (15) State (1) Server (SERVER) Procedure (Procedure) Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Is it possible to do this? If not, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not use a function call in a default variable assignment (as you found out).

Set the default to Null, and put an assignment first thing in the stored procedure.

```
  create procedure Procedure 
  (
      @fromDate datetime = NULL
  )
  begin

      set @fromDate = coalesce( @fromDate , getdate() ) 

  end
```

Comment: I asked this question years ago! Giving credit where credit is due. Thanks!